# how can vbulletin and apache share passwords

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, vbulletin

We currently have a website that uses .htaccess to control access to some pages.  We also have vBulletin running which uses a different set of credentials.  What is the best way to tie these two together so they can use the same user name and password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a vBulletin mod to take care of this.  It updates a password file used by .htaccess.  See http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?threadid=215949

Comment: Besides duplicating data, this sounds like it has the potential for danger.

Comment: Well, for us, the data was already duplicated.  At least now the duplicated data is the same.  As far as danger goes, there is the possibility.  The first version did have a security hole.  I've made it as safe as I can though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether the project is still active or whether the format that vBulletin hashes it's passwords will be suitable, but I have used a third-party Apache module under the name of "mod-auth-mysql" in the past, to integrate forum accounts with other web applications.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use an LDAP.  There are some vBulletin plugins that allow basic LDAP integration.  Apache can also be configured to authenticate via an LDAP